# Windows 10: Turning off Windows Defender's real-time protection

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

Since the times of Windows 7 I'm used to turning off Windows Defender's real-time protection, as it causes too much overhead. As a pro-user, I know what I download and I haven't caught a virus since the times of Windows XP.

However, I just upgraded to Windows 10, and it turns out that the "Turn off realtime protection" option doesn't "stick"; it is reset at every reboot. So every time I reboot my computer I have to remember to turn off real time protection.

This is very annoying. Is there a way to turn it off "forever"?

Comment: Since Windows Defender should turn off when a third-party anti-virus solution is installed, one could probably create a fake AV scanner that does nothing but reporting it’s running fine. I don’t know if it already exists, though.

Comment: The real-time aspect of it is a service? [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend]
 "Start"=dword:00000004
Also look in task Scheduler.  There is this service also [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WdNisSvc]
 "Start"=dword:00000004   I do not know anough about it yet.  Please answer your own question eventually if you figure it out.